# ogr2ogr loads spurious tables from GeoPackage using PostGIS driver

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I am loading a GeoPackage file into PostgreSQL using the following command:-

```
ogo2org -f PostgreSQL -oo LIST_ALL_TABLES=NO \
                      -lco OVERWRITE=YES \
                      -lco PG_USE_COPY=YES \
                      -lco OGR_TRUNCATE=YES \
                      -t_srs EPSG:4326 \
                      -skipfailures \
                      <DB connection string>
                      namedplaces.geopackage
```

This works but it also creates a set of spurious tables that I do not want as follows:

```
gpkg_contents
gpkg_extensions
gpkg_geometry_columns
gpkg_ogr_contents
gpkg_spatial_ref_sys
gpkg_tile_matrix
gpkg_tile_matrix_set
rtree_namedplace_geom
```

Please note these are Geopackage META-DATA tables not additional layers

I thought the LIST_ALL_TABLES=NO flag would suppress this. What am I doing wrong here?

The objective is for the command to work with any gpkg file and only load the geometry table as would happen if opened in QGIS

Comment: You need to specify a layer name (source table), or the *whole DB* is imported!

Comment: How do you specify the layer name? Does that really mean I need to run ogrinfo to get the layer name prior to ogr2ogr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tracked this behaviour down to what may be a bug/feature in the gdal geopackage driver or ogr2ogr

If the file is named with the **.gpkg** extension it works as expected

If the file is named with another extension (eg: **.geopackage**) the spurious tables are created.

Comment: From the GeoPackage standard: `Requirement 3
A GeoPackage SHALL have the file extension name ".gpkg"`.

Answer (score 1):

A *GeoPackage* is a container for arbitrary numbers of tables, a specific *SpatiaLite* implementation. This includes a set of additional *GPKG* system tables to provide certain functionality in regard to common spatial data needs, along with a different set of low level system tables used by the *SQLite* RDB core.

It also raises the need for the end-user to have an overview of its custom contents - `ogrinfo` is just one of several useful tools (e.g. the QGIS *Browser* will let you easily inspect the database). That being said, you will have to explicitly name layer(s) to import, or `ogr2ogr` executes a *full DB import*.

The generalized (from [docs](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#description)) syntax would be:

```
ogr2ogr [<general_flags>/<source_options>] <destination_datasource> <source_datasource> [<destination_options>] [<layer> [<layer> ...]]
```

so you'd simply add a list of `layer` names to the end.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced this is correct. I created a simple test file in QGIS and saved it as a Geopackage. I ran the ogr2ogr command as in my question and only a single table was loaded into Postgres. I think there is something different about either the Geopackage data file or the environment that is causing the multiple tables issue. Your answer would apply is the geopackage contained multiple layers but it only contains a single layer. The tables being loaded are metadata tables not additional layers.

Comment: @CitizenFish interesting. What are the exact build versions of both your GDAL/OGR as well as the GeoPackage in question? How was it produced? Can you check and list the full contents of your GeoPackage, including meta tables? Does it work when specifying the layer explicitly? OGR should read from `gpkg_contents`/`gpkg_ogr_contents` on initialization - how do these look like?